# Increase size of Bootstrap Tags Input before committing input

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I need to use a tags input like control to handle multiple urls to be inputted by the user in one field, with the same user experience as that of standard tags input e.g the one on stakeoverflow when you tag your questions.

Bootstrap Tags input seems to do the job well (as far as ive tested) BUT iam noticing that before you actually commit the url string to the input field, the string is truncated. After you've clicked return, the url is captured correctly as the first url on my screenshot above.

How can i increase the limit of the string url BEFORE committing the url (in edit mode) so that the user can see the full link.

Please try to paste a link as a "tag" on the bootstrap tags input first example [here](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) to test this behaviour.

If this cannot be done using this plugin, can you please suggest a plugin that has the same functionality of a tag input but more suitable for urls of any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the input box there is a width specified in it just increase it to style="width: 200px"

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" style="width: 200px !important;" size="42" data-role="tagsinput" />
```

you can set the width of it so that the value will not truncated